# How to debug NGINX Configuration

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-16.04, reverse-proxy

I have a NGINX config file where by I have added a new server block to map to a new NodeJS app I have deployed running on 8082. Initially with only the first server block, It was working, but now with an additional server block NGINX won't start.

When I run `sudo service start nginx`  or `restart` or `reload` as a substitute for `start` ; I get the below error:

```
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Checkout the config:

```
server{

    root /var/www/html;

    server_name domain1.com;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.0-fpm.sock;
    }

}

server {
    server_name domain2.com;

    location / {
     proxy_pass http://localhost:8082; 
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
         proxy_set_header Host $host;
         proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Just a sidenote, the first server block was already there and was added by the previous dev and the application to which domain1.com points to is still active, so I would hate to tamper with it.

When I run `journalctl -exe` , I get the log below and I can't make sense of it:

```
May 30 09:24:15 prod-server kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp4s0f0 OUT= MAC=68:b5:99:71:0c:a6:00:06:f6:83:fc:a0:08:00 SRC=222.228.124.121 DST=41.75.115.142 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0>
May 30 09:24:16 prod-server runsvc.sh[125206]: Starting Runner listener with startup type: service
May 30 09:24:16 prod-server runsvc.sh[125206]: Started listener process, pid: undefined
May 30 09:24:16 prod-server runsvc.sh[125206]: Runner listener fail to start with error spawn /home/cliffm/actions-runner/bin/Runner.Listener ENOENT
May 30 09:24:16 prod-server runsvc.sh[125206]: Runner listener exited with error code -2
May 30 09:24:16 prod-server runsvc.sh[125206]: Runner listener exit with undefined return code, re-launch runner in 5 seconds.
May 30 09:24:17 prod-server runsvc.sh[290543]: Starting Runner listener with startup type: service
May 30 09:24:17 prod-server runsvc.sh[290543]: Started listener process, pid: undefined
May 30 09:24:17 prod-server runsvc.sh[290543]: Runner listener fail to start with error spawn /home/cliffm/api-runner/bin/Runner.Listener ENOENT
May 30 09:24:17 prod-server runsvc.sh[290543]: Runner listener exited with error code -2
May 30 09:24:17 prod-server runsvc.sh[290543]: Runner listener exit with undefined return code, re-launch runner in 5 seconds.
May 30 09:24:17 prod-server kernel: [UFW BLOCK] IN=enp4s0f0 OUT= MAC=68:b5:99:71:0c:a6:00:06:f6:83:fc:a0:08:00 SRC=143.159.3.189 DST=41.75.115.142 LEN=44 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x0>
May 30 09:24:21 prod-server runsvc.sh[125206]: Starting Runner listener with startup type: service
May 30 09:24:21 prod-server runsvc.sh[125206]: Started listener process, pid: undefined
May 30 09:24:21 prod-server runsvc.sh[125206]: Runner listener fail to start with error spawn /home/cliffm/actions-runner/bin/Runner.Listener ENOENT
May 30 09:24:21 prod-server runsvc.sh[125206]: Runner listener exited with error code -2
May 30 09:24:21 prod-server runsvc.sh[125206]: Runner listener exit with undefined return code, re-launch runner in 5 seconds.
May 30 09:24:21 prod-server sshd[4083817]: error: kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
May 30 09:24:21 prod-server sshd[4083817]: Connection closed by [i_have_hidden_my_ip_here] port 55618
May 30 09:24:22 prod-server sudo[4083818]:   cliffm : TTY=pts/9 ; PWD=/etc/nginx ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/journalctl -ex
May 30 09:24:22 prod-server sudo[4083818]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by cliffm(uid=1002)
```

Comment: You should run `journalctl -xe` in the terminal and see what exactly is the error from nginX. Probably some typo.

Comment: @IVOGELOV, I have updated the question to show what I am getting after I run ```journalctl -exe``` . I can't seem to make sense of it.

Comment: Well, you need to run this command immediately after you try to start nginX. Also, it seems you have problems with the actions runner's listener.

Answer (score 0):

After making changes to the configs, before restart nginx is better to check the correctness of your configs:
nginx -t

```
[root@disk ~]# nginx -t
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

Now you can also run this command, it will show where the error is.

Or:

```
systemctl status nginx
```

Or:

```
journalctl -u nginx
```